# Calculate avg of column A based on specific range in column B

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. Speed(A) and elevation (B).
I want to get the average of column (A) based on a range in column (B)

for example: i want to select all rows in (B) that have a value of between -0.5 and +0.8 and get the average of the speed in (A)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need a scalar for the mean of column `'A'` where certain rows based on column `'B'` are matched, you can use `.loc` which you can read more about [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B' : [-1,0,0.1,0.2,1]})
```

---

```
>>> df
   A    B
0  1 -1.0
1  2  0.0
2  3  0.1
3  4  0.2
4  5  1.0
```

Then the following line evaluates the average of column A subset by a some condition for B:

```
>>> df.loc[df['B'].between(-0.5,0.8) , 'A'].mean()
3.0
```

Comment: Something like `df.groupby(pd.cut(df.A, [2, 4])).B.mean()` might be an option too